# Choose selectedvalue for dropdownlist bound from a different datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two dropdownlists on a webform that are populated from a query on one SQL db.  The first populates with Manufacturers part numbers, the other with the manufacturer.  The ddl's are correctly bound on page load as follows:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.DateTime
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.UI.Page
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class IQCRecord
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable
        Dim MPN As String
        Dim MFG As String
        Dim con1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=<datasource>")
        Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(order by [PREFER_49]) As Row, [MPNNUM_49] As MPN, [MPNMFG_49] As MFR, [PREFER_49] FROM [Mfg_Part_Master] WHERE ([PRTNUM_49] = @PRTNUM_49)", con1)
        cmd1.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRTNUM_49", Request.QueryString("PARTID"))
        con1.Open()

        Dim da1 As New SqlDataAdapter
        da1.SelectCommand = cmd1
        da1.Fill(dt1)

        If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
                MPN = dt1.Rows(i)("MPNNUM_49").ToString()
                ddlMPN.Items.Add(New ListItem(MPN))
                MFG = dt1.Rows(i)("MPNMFG_49").ToString()
                ddlMFG.Items.Add(New ListItem(MFG))
            Next
            ddlMPN.Items.Add(New ListItem("Wrong Part Rcv'd"))
        End If

        con1.Close()

    End If

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=<different-datasource>")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SP_GetIQCRecord", con)
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IQCID", Request.QueryString("IQC ID"))

    con.Open()

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(dt)

    lblIqcId.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("IQCID")
    txtPrtNum.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("PartID")
    txtRev.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Rev")
    txtIqcDate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("IQC DATE")
    ddlMPN.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("MPN")
    ddlMFG.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("MFG")
    txtPO.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("PO Num")
    txtVendor.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("VENDOR")
    txtInspector.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Inspector")
    lblInsID.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("InsID")
    txtLotQty.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LOT QTY")
    txtSampSize.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SAMPLE SIZE")
    txtQtyAcc.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("QTY ACC")
    txtQtyRej.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("QTY REJ")
    bolMRB.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item("MRB?")
    bolRej.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item("REJ?")
    bolpB.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item("pB")
    txtRecDC.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("REC DATE CODE")
    txtDateCode.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("DATE CODE")
    txtLotCode.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LOT CODE").ToString()
    txtRemarks.Text = If(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0).Item("REMARKS")), String.Empty, dt.Rows(0).Item("REMARKS").ToString())

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Following this binding I have another query that pulls data for a single inspection record and populates the webform, including choosing the selected value of these two ddl's.  Unfortunately, the ddl's aren't selecting the value that matches the text in the datatable.  I've verified that the dt.Rows(0).Item("MFG") and ...("MPN") are getting the values from the app db and that those values are in the bound ddl's.  I'm not getting any error, it is just not selecting the correct value.  It's just defaulting to the first value in the list.  I've included my .aspx and vb code below.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            <strong>Add/Edit Incoming Inspection Record</strong></td>
        <td class="style27">

            &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style27">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style27">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblIqcId" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPartId1" runat="server" Text="Part ID:" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrtNum" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="178px" />
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblRev" runat="server" Text="Rev:" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRev" runat="server" Height="21px" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">

            <asp:Label ID="lblIqcDate" runat="server" Text="IQC Date:" />&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIqcDate" runat="server" Height="21px" />
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMPN" runat="server" Text="MPN:" />&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMPN" runat="server"
                DataTextField="MPN" DataValueField="MPN" Height="21px" 
                Width="195px" >
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMFR" runat="server" Text="MFR:" />&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMFG" runat="server"
                DataTextField="MFG" DataValueField="MFG" Height="21px" 
                Width="159px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style26">
            <asp:Label ID="lblPO" runat="server" Text="PO Num:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPO" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="168px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style26">
            <asp:Label ID="lblVendor" runat="server" Text="Vendor:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVendor" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style26">
            <asp:Label ID="lblInspect" runat="server" Text="Inspector:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtInspector" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="160px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLotQty" runat="server" Text="Lot Qty:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLotQty" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSampSize" runat="server" Text="Sample Size:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSampSize" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="170px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style27">

            <asp:Label ID="lblInsID" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblQtyAcc" runat="server" Text="Qty Acc.:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtyAcc" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblQtyRej" runat="server" Text="Qty Rej:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtyRej" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="170px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style27">

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27" align="center">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="bolMRB" runat="server" style="text-align: right" Text="MRB?" 
                TextAlign="Left" />
        </td>
        <td class="style27" align="center">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="bolRej" runat="server" style="text-align: right" Text="Rej?" 
                TextAlign="Left" />
        </td>
        <td class="style27" align="center">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="bolpB" runat="server" style="text-align: right" Text="pB?" 
                TextAlign="Left" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblRecDC" runat="server" Text="Rec. Date Code:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRecDC" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateCode" runat="server" Text="DateCode:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateCode" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblLotCode" runat="server" Text="Lot Code:"></asp:Label>&nbsp&nbsp
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLotCode" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style28">
            </td>
        <td class="style28">
            </td>
        <td class="style28">
            </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27">
            <asp:Label ID="lblRemarks" runat="server" Text="Remarks:"></asp:Label>  
        </td>
        <td class="style27">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td class="style27">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style27" colspan="3" rowspan="3">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemarks" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="64px" 
                Width="722px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

con.Open()

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(dt)

lblIqcId.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("IQCID")
txtPrtNum.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("PartID")
txtRev.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Rev")
txtIqcDate.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("IQC DATE")
ddlMFG.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("MFG")
ddlMPN.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("MPN")
txtPO.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("PO Num")
txtVendor.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("VENDOR")
txtInspector.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Inspector")
lblInsID.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("InsID")
txtLotQty.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LOT QTY")
txtSampSize.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("SAMPLE SIZE")
txtQtyAcc.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("QTY ACC")
txtQtyRej.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("QTY REJ")
bolMRB.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item("MRB?")
bolRej.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item("REJ?")
bolpB.Checked = dt.Rows(0).Item("pB")
txtRecDC.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("REC DATE CODE")
txtDateCode.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("DATE CODE")
txtLotCode.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("LOT CODE").ToString()
txtRemarks.Text = If(IsDBNull(dt.Rows(0).Item("REMARKS")), String.Empty, dt.Rows(0).Item("REMARKS").ToString())

con.Close()
```

Comment: It sounds like a postback issue. What events are you using to grab the second query? When you change the dropdownlist or click a button?

Comment: The initial binding of the ddl's is in an "if ispostback = false" statement in the page_load event.  Following that binding, also in the page_load event but after ending the ispostback statement, is my record selection which includes the ddlMFG.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("MFG") and ddlMPN.SelectedValue = dt.Rows(0).Item("MPN") to set the selected value matching the string in the db record.

Comment: Can you post more of the code? looks like you are missing something on your page_load event.

Comment: I've added the complete page load code as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved but I can't recall on which forum I received the assistance with the code revision.  For the benefit of others I'm including the revised code that fixed my problem.

```
            Dim selectedindex As Integer = 0

        For index As Integer = 0 To dt1.Rows.Count - 1
            If dt1.Rows(index).Item("MPN") = MPN1 Then
                selectedindex = index
            End If
        Next

        ddlMPN.SelectedIndex = selectedindex
        ddlMFG.SelectedIndex = selectedindex

        con1.Close()
```